# Object field Contains arrayElements

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array:

```
string myArray={"15","56","17-75","78","100-150","130"}
```

I want to filter **myList** by **arrayElements**.

I want equivalent to code below, but programmatically:

```
mylist.Where(i=>i.val==15 || i.val==56 || (i.val >= 17 && i.val<75) ||i.val==78 || (i.val >= 100 && i.val<150)|| i.val==130)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First convert the strings to something that is more efficient to compare things to:

```
int[][] spans =
  myArray.Select(
    s => s.Split('-').Select(v => Int32.Parse(v)).ToArray()
  ).ToArray();
```

Then you can compare the items in the list to the values:

```
list.Where(i => spans.Any(s => {
  if (s.Length == 1) {
    return i == s[0];
  } else {
    return i >= s[0] && i <= s[1];
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have prepared a console application for you. Please go through it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> myQuery = null;
        List<Person> peopleList = new List<Person>();

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.Name = "x"; p1.Age = 15;
        peopleList.Add(p1);

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.Name = "y"; p2.Age = 50;
        peopleList.Add(p2);

        string[] myArray = { "15", "56", "17-75", "78", "100-150", "130" };
        foreach (string strAge in myArray)
        {
            string strLocalAge = strAge;
            if (!strLocalAge.Contains("-"))
            {
                if (myQuery == null)
                {
                    myQuery = peopleList.Where(p => p.Age == Convert.ToInt32(strLocalAge));
                }
                else
                {
                    myQuery = myQuery.Union(peopleList.Where(p => p.Age == Convert.ToInt32(strLocalAge)));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string[] agePart = strLocalAge.Split(new char[] { '-' });
                if (agePart.Length == 2)
                {

                    if (myQuery == null)
                    {
                        myQuery = peopleList.Where(p => p.Age >= Convert.ToInt32(agePart[0]) && p.Age <= Convert.ToInt32(agePart[1]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        myQuery = myQuery.Union(peopleList.Where(p => p.Age >= Convert.ToInt32(agePart[0]) && p.Age <= Convert.ToInt32(agePart[1])));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var myresult = myQuery.ToList();
        foreach (Person p in myresult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: " + p.Name + " Age: " + p.Age.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}